# Is this a complete sentence?: "The man is looking."

Tags: grammaticality

I think it may not be grammatically correct but definitely semantically incorrect.

This is because the verb 'look' requires a specific adverbial or adjectival complement to be meaningful.

The subject is looking for (at, under, in, over etc.) something. (prepositions)

The subject is looking somewhere (away, up, down, north etc.). (adverbs)

The subject is looking someway (sad, lonely, happy etc). (adjectives)

But the sentence "the man is looking" seems to leave the verb hanging without complete meaning, so even though it might feel complete it cannot be interpreted.

Comment: Such a sentence would only make sense if it had previously been made clear _what_ was being looked for or at. "We think the tickets may be in the desk drawer. Mary is looking."

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I understand that. But what I'm suggesting is that "Mary is looking there" is the 'correct' way to express this - it really needs that adverb. As a teacher I really want my students to understand the importance of complementation, so we treat a lot of sentences in isolation from context, where requirements are obvious. But still, I wonder what the grammarians here would have to say about this.

Comment: *Looking* has an idiomatic meaning as well. That said, it is not always necessary for such gerunds to have a complement or anything. "I am waiting (for whatever)"; "You are killing (me, perhaps)" ... . BTW Try to provide the context.

Comment: @Kris 'looking' in my example is not a gerund - it is a tensed verb, as are the verbs in your examples, are they not? Also the verb 'wait' is complete on its own, the sentence is not idiomatic, we can just wait, waiting is a thing in itself. 'killing' is somewhat idiomatic - but we always kill something, or something kills us, in any sense of the word idiomatic or not (I think).  'Kill,' like 'look' really requires a complement to be meaningful, doesn't it? 'wait', except in the case of 'waiters waiting', does not need a complement to complete its meaning.

Comment: @Kris - also with regard to the idiomatic uses of 'look', I'm pretty sure that these are always expressed as phrasal verbs, or in some other word form but always paired with other words to get the idiomatic meaning.

Comment: I don't think you can say 'Don't look, but I think that's Fred Astaire over there.' is any less grammatical than 'Don't look now, but I think that's Fred Astaire over there.'  However, I'd agree that the second (with the 'padding' afforded by the adverbial) is more **idiomatic** (sounds more natural). Kate's example is also idiomatic, given the (or some) acceptable prior (or possibly following) context. A bare 'Fred is looking.' is unacceptable.

Comment: I think the sentence lacks a predicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -  Thank you - I always seem to gain some insight from your comments. In your example this imperative clause works as a marker phrase for the second clause (I hope I'm getting this right, because you actually put me on to it). Or to look at it another way, if you really bare this down you end up with 'Don't look over there', which is 'look' with a required verb complement. It seems there's a relationship to the content of a verb (its potential uses, meanings, definitions) and its need for complementation.

Comment: Certainly (your last sentence). I've said elsewhere that I'd use 'Carol speeded up and sped up the hill', though many in the US probably wouldn't. You can look up 'look' in various dictionaries to see the idiosyncratic complementation requirements (or some of them) in example sentences. The patterns are complex.  // 'Don't look!' is actually totally idiomatic. Doubtless context (which need not be verbal in real-life situations) specifies the general area / situation to avert one's gaze from. But 'John is looking.' needs verbal context. // Also note that fragments are not ungrammatical per se.

Comment: @NigelJ: The sentence does not lack a predicate, it lacks a verb complement. The predicate is simply the tensed verb, but, and this is what I'm asking about, it is a grammatically incomplete predicate.

Comment: What makes the OP think it is not a gerund but a "pure" verb?

Comment: @Kris - Please define your term 'pure' verb, as I've never heard of such a thing in linguistics or prescriptive grammars.

Comment: Note the scare quotes are "pure", aha!

Answer (score 3):

The complete sentence *Look!* is grammatical: an adverb (look *where?*) can be supplied by an outstretched hand, a nod of the head, a slight movement of the eye, specifying the intended direction. Language "very often"  occurs in communicative contexts, between interlocutors, with each utterance having a function. The isolated utterance,  lying, as it were, on a laboratory table,  is not language.

It may depend on what you define a complete sentence to be. But for one thing, actual communication does not necessarily take place in "complete sentences".

You will have to add a bunch of "elided" components to transform

> Hello!

into a complete sentence.

Nevertheless

> The man is looking.

can be a meaningful utterance, said 
 by one interlocutor to another in an actual communicative context in which each utterance has an intended function, and even if such function is not clear it can be sussed out by the hearer perceiving the speaker's intention.

> Five people are watching for meteors from about 10pm to 4am on 11-12 August. The people vary in gender and age, one only of them is an adult male (or "man"),  and each one of them has an assigned quadrant and schedule. One person  will not be actively observing, or looking, at any given 20-minute interval. Who's looking for meteors from 0220 to 0240 in quadrant B? Is it the child Sammy who's looking? No. The man is looking.

Comment: I greet you. I like this answer because it is an interesting comment on what constitutes language at such higher level attributes. I should've provided the context that I asking the question from a more limited perspective that pertains primarily to formal speech and writing, not casual or perfunctory communication. _Look!_ as you've described nicely captures the verb's need for complementation in any form. Elision is certainly an interesting aspect of acceptable constructions. (I always end up teaching the missing parts and challenge students to find them in other sentences.)

Comment: Your example is also interesting because of the context it develops before it gives the uncomplemeted verb enough of it to make the final sentence fully meaningful. The first three uses of the verb 'look' are in the gerund form as complements of other verbs.  I think the only way 'look' can function grammatically as a main verb without a complement is as an answer to a question. I think there are quite a few verbs that work like this, in as much as they don't really have enough content to be fully meaningful without a complement. Thanks, this was a really interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if something like this is semantically [in]correct requires more than a single, isolated sentence, e.g. "No one knew where to find him. The police came looking. Then the FBI did. And I'm still looking." Coherence [can be maintained despite/via ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(linguistics)#Ellipsis).

Comment: In your sentence, looking is a gerund complement.I'm asking about look as the main verb.

Comment: @UbuEnglish: I'm not seeing the grammatical difference between "I'm looking" and "the man is looking" (other than conjugation). Your example is not "The man looks.", although one can easily come with an ellipsis example for that as well.

Comment: ... actually found one with google: "The Yo-Yo Man points to his yo-yo, the man looks, reflects, shows a pitying look, reaches in his pocket taking out some coins." Ignoring the run-on sentence issue, it's obvious what's elided in "looks".

Comment: My bad, I missed the gist. In order for the uncomplemented form to be meaningful requires a lot of context - you used the verb as a gerund twice (the latter by ellipsis) in order to make the final form clearly interpretable. And, you use the conjunction 'And' as a discourse marker (I think that's what it's called); so the last sentence might as well be part of the previous one. Without it, the meaning is less clear. But 'still' is also providing context with referents. Bared to 'they're looking' (the original post's form) and it feels to me, I'm left hanging for meaning.

Comment: Great link, btw, thx.